# Only one prime ideal above prime ideal of base field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a imaginary quadratic field of class number $1$ and let $L/K$ be a finite extension and $P$ be $K$'s nonzero prime ideal.

Are there some sufficient condition of 'prime of $L$ above $P$ is unique' ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For there to exist ramification.

Comment: Even if there exists ramification, I think there are many cases where prime above $P$ is not unique. Could you tell me why ramification implies there is only one prime ?

Comment: Why $pO_L＝(B_1B_2・・・B_g)^e$, $e≧2$ imply $g＝1$ in this situation ?

Comment: Sorry yes, you need there to be lots of ramification (i.e., $e\ge[L:K]$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a primitive element we get $L=K(\alpha)\cong K[x]/(f)$.

Then a prime $\mathfrak{p}\subset O_K$ has only one prime above it iff $f$ is irreducible in $K_\mathfrak{p}$. So this is about irreducilibity of polynomials in $\mathfrak{p}$-adic completions (finite extensions of $p$-adic fields).

Comment: I didn't notice that, could you tell me your statement ?

Answer (score 0):

As in any extension of number fields, what you want is for the minimal polynomial of the extension to remain irreducible mod $p$ (or to be a perfect square, since you are allowing ramification). As with any abelian extension, this will be determined by congruence conditions on $p$ (with a finite number of exceptions for ramified primes).

There are a finite number of these fields, so you could just look up those congruence conditions.